# Integrated card for graphics; ATI card for computing

Tags: graphics-card

I picked up a [Dell Optiplex 760](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/optix/Optiplex_brochure_760_isen.pdf) at an auction. It came with a an integrated graphics card as well as an [ATI Radeon card](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/224/radeon-hd-3450.html). The ATI card has only an S-video output and some sort of DVI output, so I use the VGA output of the integrated card currently for my graphics display.Meanwhile, the ATI card sits in a drawer.

Insteading of collecting dust in a drawer, I would like to use the ATI card as an opportunity to learn OpenCL. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use the add-on card soley for computing with the integrated card simultaneously being used for display. The BIOS options are shown below:

[image]

If I use the "Auto" option, I'm confronted with this screen on boot:

[image]

But if I use the second, option my the ATI card of course overrides the integrated card. Do I have any other options?

Comment: "has only an S-video output and some sort of DVI output" - This isn't specific enough.  You can't have it both ways.  Programs can use the GPU if its not your primary display adapter, which is what the message is about, you don't have the hardware that allows you to use both.  Both screenshots is clear, if you want to use the external GPU, you have to plug your monitor into it.  The specifications for the card are specific, it should have a VGA port, even the specifications for the computer indicate that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The ATI card has only S-video and DVI outputs. I use neither. The integrated card has only a VGA output, which is what I currently use for my display.

Comment: The card you linked to indicates it has a VGA output.  The specifications on the computer indicates the external GPU has a VGA output.  It doesn't really matter you can't use both, your hardware won't allow it, and it can't be made to work.  [Purchase a cheap DVI to VGA adapter.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dvi%20to%20vga)

Comment: [Provide specifics about the DVI port.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)

Comment: @Ramhound It's probable that he got the Desktop variant, which only has Low Form Factor PCI slots. The Video Card will have had the VGA port removed, and should have come with one of [these](http://www.lunashops.com/goods.php?id=444). They're a real pain.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Those cables are the best :-)

Comment: Yes, it is the desktop variant, and the VGA has been removed. I'm asking if it is possible to use the ATI card only for computations, not for display, while simultaneously using the integrated card for display.

Comment: @Ramhound Not when they go missing during an office shift. We never had enough.

Comment: @Chester - I don't think it's possible for these computers. They were designed to use the PCI graphics card if it was installed, which is why you get that error message.